# What is the xpath expression for a BigDecimalInstantiation PMD rule for java

Tags: java, xpath, pmd

I want to create a custom PMD rule that eliminates instantiation of BigDecimal objects (ie. new BigDecimal(value) ). I need to enforce the BigDecimal.valueof(value) implementation.

I have no idea how to implement this. Are there some examples i can use?

Thanks,
Bas Hendriks

Comment: What is "PMD"? Why do you think this question is related to XPath?

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: While the reference to XPath in the title might be misleading. [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net) rules are mostly developed with rule properties based on XPath.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev: This may explain the reason for the XPath tag: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/xpathruletutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the implementation of [IntegerInstantiation](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.0/rules/java/migrating.html#IntegerInstantiation) as an example.

But make sure not to forbid the usage of all the BigDecimal constructors. There are only three `BigDecimal.valueOf` methods, and the ones taking a long as arguments are the only ones which should be preferred over calling a constructor.

The one taking a double just calls the constructor anyway, and constructing BigDecimal with double values should be discouraged anyway.

Comment: +1 for making sure highlighting that you shouldn't write a blanket rule.